# Solving for equivalent resistance w/ short circuiting

Tags: thevenin, norton

[image: Circuit]

I am working on finding the equivalent norton and thevenin circuits. To fond the equivalent resistance, I zero out any sources. When this happens, according to my professor. Only the 10 ohm resistor to the left is short circuited as a result of the zeroing. Why is this the case? Why is the 12 ohm resistor not also short circuited by zeroing out any sources?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the 12 ohm resistor not also short circuited by zeroing out any sources?

When you zero out a current source, you make a 0 A current source. That is, an open circuit, not a short circuit.

Comment: So the rules is that zeroing a voltage source short circuits it but zeroing a current source sets current to 0. Or rather, zeroing a voltage source sets its voltage to 0 but current can still flow while zeroing a current source sets its current to 0. Seems I misunderstood zeroing. Thanks a lot Photon.

Comment: yes, that's correct.